# SQL Count Distinct returning one extra count

Tags: sql

How is this possible that these two methods are returning different results?

**Method 1** (returns correct count):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id)
FROM Traffic_Action
WHERE action_type IN ('Schedule a Tour', 'Schedule Follow-up', 'Lost')
```

**Method 2** (returns one extra count):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN action_type IN ('Schedule a Tour', 'Schedule Follow-up', 'Lost') THEN contact_id ELSE 0 END)
FROM Traffic_Action
```

Comment: In standard SQL you could also write `count(distinct contact_id) filter (where action_type in (...))`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `else part` - as 0 is also counted

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN 
    action_type in ('Schedule a Tour','Schedule Follow-up','Lost') THEN contact_id END) 
FROM Traffic_Action
```

Answer (score 1):

No wonder you are getting two different results.

First query:

Provides you the distinct count of records where `action_type in Schedule a Tour, Schedule Follow-up and Lost`

```
SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT contact_id) FROM    Traffic_Action WHERE   action_type in 
('Schedule a Tour','Schedule Follow-up','Lost')
```

Second query:

In this query any value apart from `Schedule a Tour, Schedule Follow-up and Lost` is considered as `0`, and on taking distinct value, results one row according to your case statement

```
SELECT    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN action_type in ('Schedule a Tour','Schedule Follow- 
up','Lost') THEN contact_id ELSE 0 END) FROM    Traffic_Action
```

In simple words,

In first query you are filtering only three values

In second query you have no filters, but case statement on three values and else condition to return 0 for non matching criteria

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

That means you have 1 record where contact_id is NULL.  Normally, COUNT() ignores NULL values. Your second query converts NULL to zero via the "ELSE" branch. That should be why you see a difference.

You can quickly see for yourself in this example. This will return 2 although there are 3 records

```
select count(distinct a.col1)
from (
    select 1 as Col1
    union select 2
    union select NULL
) a
```